# Tabbed Viewpager inside AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-alertdialog

I am unable to create a Custom AlertDialog with a Tabbed ViewPager in it. I was able to create a DialogFragment with it in onCreateView. But when I tried to change it to an AlertDialog I adapted (tried to) the code to the onCreateDialog method but was unsuccessful after many tries.

The error I get is:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.yoyo.bonosconsulta, PID: 28495
              java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment does not have a view
```

If instead of inflating the view with dialog_viewpager.xml, I inflate it with fragment_date.xml (and remove the following 7 lines of code), it doesn't give any error. So the problem lies either in the viewpager or the tablayout, I guess.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the onCreateView:

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder =  new  AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
            .setPositiveButton("OK",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                            int whichButton) {
                            ((MainActivity) getActivity())
                                    .doPositiveClick();
                        }
                    })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                            int whichButton) {
                            ((MainActivity) getActivity())
                                    .doNegativeClick();
                        }
                    });

    LayoutInflater i = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View rootview = i.inflate(R.layout.dialog_viewpager,null);

    tabLayout = rootview.findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
    viewPager = rootview.findViewById(R.id.masterViewPager);
    TabbedDialogAdapter adapter = new TabbedDialogAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment("Date", TabbedDateFragment.createInstance("John"));
    adapter.addFragment("Time", TabbedTimeFragment.createInstance("Stacy"));
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    builder.setView(rootview);
    return builder.create();
}
```

Here's dialog_viewpager.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/masterViewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
```

Here's TabbedDialogAdapter:

```
public class TabbedDialogAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
List<Fragment> mFragmentCollection = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> mTitleCollection = new ArrayList<>();
public TabbedDialogAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}
public void addFragment(String title, Fragment fragment)
{
    mTitleCollection.add(title);
    mFragmentCollection.add(fragment);
}
//Needed for
@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return mTitleCollection.get(position);
}
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return mFragmentCollection.get(position);
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mFragmentCollection.size();
}
```

}

And finally fragment_date.xml (fragment_time.xml is similar)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
<DatePicker
    android:id="@+id/dp_datepicker"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@color/LVcolor"
    />
```

For completion purposes, when I had the onCreateView() and it worked (but without the AlertDialog buttons, the code was this:

```
    @Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_viewpager,container,false);
    tabLayout = rootview.findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
    viewPager = rootview.findViewById(R.id.masterViewPager);
    TabbedDialogAdapter adapter = new TabbedDialogAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment("Date", TabbedDateFragment.createInstance("John"));
    adapter.addFragment("Time", TabbedTimeFragment.createInstance("Stacy"));
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    return rootview;
}
```

Comment: Can you share your error log?

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.yoyo.bonosconsulta, PID: 28495
                  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment does not have a view

Answer (score 0):

It might be a lot easier if you implement it in a normal activity, and give your activity a theme like `Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog`

Comment: If you mean creating the alertdialog within an Activity, I just tried that (in MainActivity. Same error code.